# java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-01747: invalid user.table.column, table.column, or column specification

Tags: oracle

```
UPDATE TMP_OP_USPORTCALLS_RPT 
SET CARGO_QTY =  ( 
    SELECT A.CARGO_QUANTITY FROM ( 
        SELECT CASE WHEN (SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0))) > 0 THEN ROUND(SUM(NVL(QUANTITY,0))) END AS CARGO_QUANTITY 
        FROM OP_POSITION_CARGO 
        WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2 
        AND SHIP_ID = '380' 
        AND COMMODITY_ID = 816 
        AND KEY_POSITION = (
            SELECT KEY_POSITION 
            FROM OP_POSITION_DETAILS 
            WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2 AND SHIP_ID = '380' AND VOYAGE_NO = 152 
            AND KEY_POSITION = 800892 
            AND EVENT_ID = ( 
                SELECT EVENT_ID    
                FROM MA_EVENT 
                WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2 AND UPPER(EVENT_NAME) LIKE 'LOAD%'
            ) 
        ) 
        GROUP BY KEY_POSITION, COMMODITY_ID,UNIT_CODE 
    ) A) 
WHERE COMPANY_ID = 2 AND SHIP_ID = '380' AND VOYAGE_NO = 152 
AND KEY_POSITION = 800892 AND COMMODITY_ID = 816 AND QUERY_ID = '1476272548543'
```

This is my query , Can anyone tell where I made mistake

Comment: One of your column names is wrong. It's impossible to tell without seeing the schemas of all the tables.

Comment: I have checked my table twice , column name is correct only.Is there any other thing except column name to cause this error.

Comment: I don't use Oracle, but the error message seems very clear that it's a column name problem. Is there any more to the error that says which table and column is the error?

Comment: Do you really have all those columns in both the `TMP_OP_USPORTCALLS_RPT` and `OP_POSITION_DETAILS` tables?

Comment: please execute desc TMP_OP_USPORTCALLS_RPT; desc OP_POSITION_CARGO; desc OP_POSITION_DETAILS; desc MA_EVENT and post the results if you still need some help